# Locating town named Tavlik(?) near Lithuania

Tags: historical-gazetteer, lithuania

I have recordings of my grandfather's cousin interviewing his father about life in Lithuania during the late 1800s and early 1900s. My great great grandfather describes his life as a young child, in particular, a story about his family losing wealth due to a new law.

> But, uh, after it comes out a law, that no Jewish can have, uh, la—
>   land in, uh, uh, fifty miles from the border, and they used to live
>   re— less than fifty miles from the border of [unclear, maybe, Tavlik],
>   so they, they was chased out from the land.

He says later,

> No, they did not pay nothing at all. They just chased, chased them off
>   and that’s all. They did not pay a nothing.

- I have two questions. The first is, he mentions a town-- what sounds like 'Tavlik'. What are its longitude and latitude.
- The second is the validity of this story. Where can I find more about this event? I understand that throughout the 17th - early 20th century, the Pale of Settlement dictated where Jews could live, but I couldn't find the one instance he was referring to.

Some clues:

- He was born in 1883.
- He was born on a farm between Pumpyan [55°56' 24°21’] and Posvol [56°04' N, 24°24' E]
- As a result of the loss in wealth, the father went to peddle in Ponovich.

(The spelling 'Tavlik' is a phonetic transcription of what he says during the interview. The sound is sub-par. It's possible I've spelled or heard wrong. I would post a snippet of the recording but I don't think I can do that on this site.)

Comment: Could it possibly be Tērvete, which is a municipal area of Latvia, right on the Lithuanian border?

Answer (score 1):

I'll make a guess that this might be what was known as Шавли in 1890, just south of the 56th parallel:

[image: Lithuania 1888]
([Lithuanianmaps.com](http://www.lithuanianmaps.com/images/1888_KovnoGub_copy.jpg))

Russian maps of the time put the zero meridian on the Pulkovo Observatory near St Petersburg: the vertical line is labelled "−7".

Шавли would be pronounced *Shavli* which could sound like "Tavlik" in a poor recording of an elderly man.

The city is now called Шяуля́й (Shyaulyai) and Wikipedia even gives a Yiddish name, שאַװל (Shavel). It's listed as 55°56′N 23°19′E.

Comment: https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/shavli/shavli1.html has information related to the history of Jewish people in that place.